# Generating Threaded RSS / ATOM Feeds

Tags: rss, rome, threaded-comments

I want to generate a RSS feed that can be displayed threaded in RSS-Clients.

So if the feed describes something like comments or changes to one and the same entity, i want these to be visually grouped.

Is this possible in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [ATOM Threading Extensions](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4685.txt) that will do the job. Atom Feeds will be displayed threaded in Thunderbird / Outlook when those are used.

They should be pretty simple to implement for any RSS-Library. For [rome](https://github.com/rometools/rome) i published a [rome-module](https://github.com/rometools/rome-modules) that can be used.